# Fire IE plugin does not display data net panel

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I have added Fire IE plugin to FF, then I opened the IE specific URL (the site which supports on IE browser) in FF and I am trying to open debug mode, but it shows the blank in net panel.

How will I be able to get the data in net panel?

[image: Net Panel using Fire IE add-on]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Internet Explorer (probably MSHTML) handles all the HTTP requests when you're in IE mode, so you won't be able to use the Firefox devtools.

However, if you open up IE, it has its own developer tools you can use.

Answer (score 0):

Hey followed your steps and all working fine for me.

May be you need to Enable Net panel. Refer Provided Image.

Also make sure you tick on all 4 options.

[image]